# iPhone - make VoiceOver announce label text change

Tags: iphone, wai-aria, voiceover

Is it possible using VoiceOver on the iPhone to announce the updated text on a label if it changes?

This would be analogous to a live-region in ARIA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

You can make VoiceOver announce any text you like with:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, @"Your text");
```

If a label should announce its text as soon as it is updated, simply extend the `UILabel` and override the `setText` method.

The .h File:

```
@interface UIVoicedLabel : UILabel {

}

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
#import "UIVoicedLabel.h"

@implementation UIVoicedLabel

- (void) setText:(NSString *)text {
    // Set the text by calling the base class method.
    [super setText:text];
    // Announce the new text.
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, text);
}

@end
```

This worked perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Swift 4 version

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.announcement, argument: "Your text")
```