# Can I tell iOS when it's in VoiceOver mode to read aloud a specific UILabel's text when I change it?

Tags: ios, ipad, voiceover

I've got a label that's going to change to say something silly like "the sky is now blue" and I'd like to have VoiceOver read that new text aloud without a semi-blind user needing to press on the label.

Is that possible however, to direct VoiceOver to read a specific item when & where I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See this answer: [iPhone - make VoiceOver announce label text change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520238/iphone-voiceover-make-voice-over-announce-label-text-change)

In short, you can tell iOS to speak text aloud when in voiceover mode by sending notifications, like:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, @"the sky is now blue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out how to "focus" on a particular UIAccessibilityElement (i.e. make it as if they had tapped it), but I think in your case you could use `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification` to speak arbitrary text.